# Parsing in a String for a specific value

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am getting a return string from web service that I am calling. Now I want to look for specific value which should be present in that return string. Return string is something like this:

> pg_response_type=A
>   pg_response_code=A01
>   pg_response_description=APPROVED
>   endofdata

Now I want to check in this string that if **pg_response_code=A01** is present or not. I know I have to for loop in the string. What should be the code...? Suppose I am storing this string in `string Response;`

Comment: Whats wrong with the `Contains` method? e.g `if (response.Contains("pg_response_code=A01")...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx):

```
bool contains = response.Contains("pg_response_code=A01")
```

Answer (score 1):

Without writing a parser or looping you can still check for specific values like this:

```
string response; //response in here.

if(response.contains("pg_response_code=A01"))
{
 //do something
}
```